# JAXB ignores property if boolean method with is-prefix defined

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This simple 1-prop class works fine and can be ummarshaled

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class AdditionalGetter {
    private float a;

    @XmlElement(name = "my_prop_a", required = false)
    public float getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(float a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    // public boolean isA() {
    //    return true;
    // }
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<additionalGetter>
    <my_prop_a>7.0</my_prop_a>
</additionalGetter>
```

but if i uncomment the line with method isA() it does not work anymore and output ist just (on win):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<additionalGetter/>
```

So it looks like a naming conflict for JAXB. Actually acessor type none should ignore othef fields, but isA() methods stops a-field from being marschaled.

So an oblivious way to fix it, just to rename method isA() to avoid conflict. But i would like to know:

1) Is this really prohibited by JAXB? If yes, where is this descriebed?

2) Is any way to make marshaling work, without renaming this method (and breaking an existing jar-interface)? I have tryed @XmlTransient with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `@XmlTransient` in front of `public boolean isA()`, this prevents jaxb to include the method in the generated xml.

```
@XmlTransient
public boolean isA() {
    return true;
}
```